# conditional expectation of power law distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'd be interested in solving problem 2.2 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276369/can-anyone-shed-some-light-on-the-below-statistical-theory-questions). The OP posted three questions in a single thread so thought it could be useful to split the questions. Apologies if this is a duplicate thread.

Suppose that $X$ has a power law distribution $P(X > x) = a x^{-b}$ for $x > x_0 > 0$ and some $a > 0$, $b > 1$. Calculate the conditional expectation $ E(X|X>x)$ , $x> x_0$

Here's my attempt. [This may be interesting in tackling the problem](http://larrylisblog.net/WebContents/Interview%20Preparations/ABoundProblemForCE.pdf)

$P(X>0) = \int_x^{\infty} a s^{-b} ds = - \frac{a}{1-b} x^{-b+1}$, using $b>1$

$P(X|X>x) = \frac{P(X \in ds, X>x)}{P(X>x)} = \frac{P(X\in ds)}{P(X>x)}$

$E(X|X>x) =- \frac{1-b}{a}x^{b-1} \int_x^{\infty} a s s^{-b} ds$

This is probably wrong because the problem only states that $b>1$ and the integral in the expression above leads to $ \frac{a}{2-b}s^{2-b} $ where $s$ needs to be evaluated as $s\rightarrow \infty$, where the expression does not get squeezed if $1<b<2$

Tnx

Comment: What does exactly mean the notation "$P(X\in ds, X>x)$"? I have seen it already several times but I cannot find any reference in the literature to what it exactly means. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b\gt1$, then $x_0=a^{1/b}$ and, for every $x$,
$$
E(X\mid X\gt x)=\frac{b}{b-1}\,\max\{x,x_0\}.
$$
To show this, it may help to use that the density $f_X$ of $X$ is such that, for every $x$,
$$
f_X(x)=\frac{ab}{x^{b+1}}\,\mathbf 1_{x\geqslant x_0},
$$
and that
$$
E(X;X\gt x)=\int_x^\infty tf_X(t)\,\mathrm dt.
$$

Comment: Is this answer correct? For $b > 2$ I get a different result. I find also counter-intuitive that the result above does not depend on $x$. Thanks.

Comment: It was not, in particular for the reason you mention. See revised version and thanks for asking.

Comment: Got it, thanks. One last question: why is $x_0 = a^{1/b}$?

Comment: Because $P(X\gt x_0)=1$.

Comment: Right. Of course. Thank you.

Comment: @Did -- sorry to bring this up after a while. But why have you used $max(x,x_{0})$ instead of just $x$ in your answer? In the question it was assumed that $x$ > $x_0$. So can't we simplify $max(x,x_{0})$ to $x$ ? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @fushsialatitude The question may have assumed $x\gt x_0$, I have not. Hence the formula in my answer is more general than strictly necessary. Indeed, if $x\geqslant x_0$ then $\max\{x,x_0\}=x$ (is this your question?).

Comment: @did yes thanks that's fine.

Comment: Doesn't the right side in the last equation have to be scaled (i.e. divided by $P(X>x)$)?

Comment: @SimonMarkett No, you are confusing E(X;A) with E(X|A) = E(X;A) / P(A), for A = [X>x].

Comment: Ah, yes, makes sense. Cheers